# Add a new Role Center On Dynamics 365 Business Cental

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I am working on an AL programming project in order to add new functionality to the existing Business central .I am trying to add a new button on the role center
like shown in the image. I want to add "Gestion des compétences et des carriéres".
Is that possible? And how can i do it please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4oAS.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

so, the thing that you want do it is possible.
But, in that SPECIFIC place is not.
In order to have your function into your role center you have to use the page extension object into your code, adding the page reference your Role center (obviusly it is not possible if your role center is custom one).
Here, i add for you the official documentation of Microsoft about it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-designing-role-centers